# What do you call your non-admin role?

Tags: labeling

I've come up with these.

- Basic User
- Regular User
- Default User

Other ideas? Which is best?

Comment: How about 'minion'? Or 'data-peasant?' ; )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In trivial problems I stick with simply "User" and "Administrator".

However most systems have specialisations of User: Customer, Supplier, Clerk, ... These are more informative and make more sense when describing scenarios: "Customer submits Order", "Supplier ships Order".  So I only go with "User" in the absence of more meaningful problem-domain terms.

hth.